# Retrieve values from fragment on swipe in ViewPager - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a registration screens using `ViewPager` where user will give all the details and clicks `Submit` button in the last fragment.

On swiping each fragment I have to validate the data and have save it to an object in Activity which has the `ViewPager`. I can't find a perfect way to do that.

Below is my code snippet

**RegistrationActivity.java**

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MultiPurposeDialogListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 4;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private boolean isActivityVisible;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// Have to save data in these object
public Employee Employee = newEmployee();
public EmpDetails empDetails = new EmpDetails();
public Devices devices = new Devices();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return RegistrationSlideFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

**RegistrationSlideFragment.java**

```
    public static RegistrationSlideFragment create(int pageNumber) {
    RegistrationSlideFragment fragment = new RegistrationSlideFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registraion_slide, container, false);

    TextView tx = (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading);
    LinearLayout ln_slide1 = (LinearLayout) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.ln_slide1);
    LinearLayout ln_slide2 = (LinearLayout) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.ln_slide2);
    LinearLayout ln_slide3 = (LinearLayout) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.ln_slide3);
    LinearLayout ln_slide4 = (LinearLayout) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.ln_slide4);
    Button btn_leftarrow = (Button) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.btn_leftarrow);
    Button btn_rightarrow = (Button) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.btn_rightarrow);
    Button btn_submit = (Button) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);


    if ((mPageNumber + 1) == 1) {
        btn_leftarrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ed_dob = (EditText) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
        ed_fname = (EditText) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
        ed_lname = (EditText) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
        ed_email = (EditText) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
        ed_country = (EditText) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.et_dob);

        ed_dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                newFragment.show(fm, "DatePicker");
            }
        });

        tx.setText("Personal Details");
        ln_slide1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if ((mPageNumber + 1) == 2) {
        sp_availability = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_availability);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_availability = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.proj_availability, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp_availability.setAdapter(adapter_availability);


        chk_tot_performance = (CheckBox) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chk_tot_performance);
        chk_tot_functional = (CheckBox) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chk_tot_functional);
        chk_tot_localozation = (CheckBox) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chk_tot_localization);
        chk_tot_security = (CheckBox) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chk_tot_security);
        chk_tom_native = (CheckBox) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chk_tom_native);
        chk_tom_hybrid = (CheckBox) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chk_tom_hybrid);
        chk_tom_web = (CheckBox) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chk_tom_web);


        tx.setText("Project Prefetance");
        ln_slide2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if ((mPageNumber + 1) == 3) {
        sp_functional = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_functional);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_functional = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.testing_expertise, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp_functional.setAdapter(adapter_functional);

        sp_security = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_security);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_security = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.testing_expertise, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp_security.setAdapter(adapter_security);

        sp_performance = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_performance);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_performance = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.testing_expertise, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp_performance.setAdapter(adapter_performance);

        sp_localization = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_localization);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_localization = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.testing_expertise, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp_localization.setAdapter(adapter_localization);


        tx.setText("Test Expertise");
        ln_slide3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if ((mPageNumber + 1) == 4) {
        btn_rightarrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn_submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sp_network = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_network_type);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_networkstatus = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.networktype, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp_network.setAdapter(adapter_networkstatus);

        sp_manufaturer = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_manufacturer);
        sp_device_name = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_device_name);
        sp_version = (Spinner) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.sp_os_version);
        sp_manufaturer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                setDeviceList("devicecompactability_devicelist.json", parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        tx.setText("Your Device Details");
        ln_slide4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setManufacturerList("devicecompactability_devicelist.json");
        setVersionList("devicecompactability_platformversion.json");

    }


    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Object> finalObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
            finalObject.add(registrationActivity.Employee);
            finalObject.add(registrationActivity.empDetails);
            finalObject.add(registrationActivity.devices);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String resultJson = gson.toJson(finalObject);
            System.out.println(resultJson);
        }
    });


    return viewGroup;
}
```

Comment: Save your values in arrayList as users navigates the registration screens and then at the last fragment, iterate through the ArrayList. Make the ArrayList public !

Answer (score 3):

We got the same (i suppose) wizard system in our application.

So we decided not to retrieve data on swipe, but on data change itself. So we made a interfaces for each fragment, which activity does implement like (for example)

```
onDataChange(long datetime)
```

or

```
onTitleChange(String newTitle)
```

which passed to activity (we bind interface to fragment in fragment's method `onAttach`) when it passes validation in fragment (end of edittext editing via TextWatcher, radiobuttons and checkboxes via their change listeners, etc). We have a model object, so interface implementation looks like this in our activity

```
    public void onTitleChange(String newTitle)  {
       model.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
```

The last fragment passes "submit button event" as `onDataSubmit()` and in activity we do the logic (saving to database and then sending over network).

Also, we save our model object in activity in `onSaveInstanceState` to persist changes in case activity got destroyed before submitting our changes to network/database.